# finding the limit of the integral of an unknown function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

I have a question from an exam written 18 years ago, and I can't solve it (I'm solving old questions to prepare for my own exam).

### The Question

The question goes like so:

let  g be a function, which has a derivative defined $\forall x\in [-1,1]$, and $g(0)=0,g'(0)=1$.
Does the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\left(\int\limits _{x^{3}}^{x^{2}}\left(\int\limits _{0}^{t}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds\right)dt\right)}{x^{8}}$$ converge?

### What have I tried?

I thought about using L'Hôpital's rule, and F.T.C. so I wrote:

$$\left(\int\limits _{x^{3}}^{x^{2}}\left(\int\limits _{0}^{t}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds\right)dt\right)'=2x\int\limits _{0}^{x^{2}}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds-3x^{2}\int\limits _{0}^{x^{3}}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds$$

but that didn't help much. I can even show that the limit is of the form $"\frac{0}{0}"$ to use the rule.

I tested this on $g(x)=x$ and it seems like this limit does converge (to 0 if I'm not mistaken)

I also thought Taylor was somehow related, but I really doubt it. I am also unsure of where the information we have about $g(0),g'(0)$ comes in.

BTW

this is what I got after applying L'Hôpital once

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(2\int\limits _{0}^{x^{2}}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds-3x\int\limits _{0}^{x^{3}}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds\right)\cos\left(\int\limits _{x^{3}}^{x^{2}}\left(\int\limits _{0}^{t}g\left(s^{2}\right)ds\right)dt\right)}{8x^{6}}$$

Comment: You have only applied L'Hopital once. Why not keep using it?

Comment: That is just the numerator, L'Hopital has to be done on both. Consider the $x^8$ in the original numerator, and you will probably have to L'Hopital again.

Comment: @mrsamy I updated the answer and showed what I got after one iteration of L'Hopital, doing this 6 times more doesn't seem like a good option. Also, I don't even know how to show the limit is of form "0/0" (as I said), so Im not even sure if Im allowed to use the rule

Comment: @NinadMunshi please see the comment I wrote for mrsamy

Comment: It's incorrect, it should be a cosine off to the right

Comment: Have you heard of something called "Taylor series"?

Comment: @NinadMunshi fixed, thank you

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes, I wrote at the end of the question I thought I might be able to use Taylor somehow, but I can see how. If I want to write a series for g, I only know $g(0), g'(0)$ so I can't go on to infinity

Comment: For your question, you don't need all terms, just a few.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I was able to write $$f\left(x\right)=g\left(x^{2}\right),\;\sum_{n=0}^{2}\frac{f^{\left(n\right)}\left(0\right)}{n!}\left(x-0\right)^{n}=0+1+R_{2}\left(x\right)=o\left(x^{2}\right)$$ but now this doesn't look like something I can just plug in the integral

Comment: You can remove the $\sin$ via standard limits and set $G(t) =\int_0^t g(s^2)\,ds,F(u)=\int_0^u G(t) \, dt$ and use LHospital Rule to get $F(u) /u^4\to 1/12$ as $u\to 0$. Your desired limit is $1/12$.

Comment: This is one scenario where LHospital Rule should be used as it gives the answer instantly without any effort.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Im not sure I understand how you removed the $\sin$ and used LHospital

Comment: Since $(\sin x) /x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ you can get rid of sine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I think I'm missing something... I don't see anything of the form $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Somebody posted an answer so perhaps it will make things more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer based on my comments.

Let $$G(t) =\int_{0}^{t}g(s^2)\,ds,F(u)=\int_{0}^{u}G(t)\,dt$$ Then we have $$F'(u) =G(u), G'(t) =g(t^2)$$ and hence by two applications of LHospital Rule we get $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{F(u)}{u^4}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{G(u)}{4u^3}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{g(u^2)}{12u^2}=\frac {1}{12}$$ The limit in question is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(F(x^2)-F(x^3))}{x^8}$$ Since $F(x^2)\to 0,F(x^3)\to 0$ we can write the expression under limit as $$\frac {\sin(F(x^2)-F(x^3))}{F(x^2)-F(x^3)}\cdot \frac {F(x^2)-F(x^3)}{x^8}$$ and the first factor tends to $1$ so the limit equals the limit of second factor.

Now we can write $$\frac{F(x^2)-F(x^3)}{x^8}=\frac {F(x^2)}{x^8}-x^4\cdot\frac{F(x^3)}{x^{12}}$$ which tends to $$\frac {1}{12}-0\cdot\frac {1}{12}=\frac {1}{12}$$

---

LHospital Rule is a very powerful tool for evaluation of limits, but it has become infamous due to the crappy ways in which it is used frequently by beginners.

It is possible to avoid LHospital and use $\epsilon, \delta$ and integrating inequalities.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! the limit of $\frac{g(u^2)}{u^2}$ is obtained using L'hospitals rule, right?

Comment: @snatchysquid: no, that limit is by definition of derivative and $g'(0)=1$.

Comment: @snatchysquid: don't use LHospital more than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Let us write

\begin{equation}g (x) = x h (x)\end{equation}

so that $h (x) \rightarrow  1$ when $x \rightarrow  0$. Let us first substitute $s = t u$ in the integral

\begin{equation}I \left(x\right) \colon  = \int_{{x}^{3}}^{{x}^{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{t}g \left({s}^{2}\right) d s\right) d t = \int_{{x}^{3}}^{{x}^{2}}\left(\int_{0}^{t}{s}^{2} h \left({s}^{2}\right) d s\right) d t = \int_{{x}^{3}}^{{x}^{2}}{t}^{3} \left(\int_{0}^{1}u^2h \left({t}^{2} {u}^{2}\right) d u\right) d t\end{equation}

Now let us substitute $t = {x}^{2} v$, it follows that

\begin{equation}I \left(x\right) = {x}^{8} \int_{x}^{1}v^3\left(\int_{0}^{1} u^2h \left({x}^{4} {u}^{2} {v}^{2}\right) d u\right) d v \sim  {x}^{8} \int_{0}^{1}{v}^{3} \left(\int_{0}^{1}u^2 d u\right) d v = \frac{{x}^{8}}{12}\end{equation}

As $\sin  \left({\theta}\right) \sim  {\theta}$ when ${\theta} \rightarrow  0$ it follows that the limit is $1/12$.

Comment: Shouldn't the limit be $1/12$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not infallible. Is there a mistake in the above?

Comment: An easy way to check is using $g(x) =x$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  I think the mistake is corrected. I forgot $u^2$ in the inner integral. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, I have a few questions. what esnures us the existence of a function $h$ as described? In the last row, why did the integral bounds change from $x^2,x^3$ to $1,x$? And lastly, how and why are we allowed to used here the "~" symbol?

Comment: The function $h$ exists because it is equal to $g(x)/x$ when $x\not = 0$ and to $1$ when $x = 0$. The conditions on $g$ ensure that $h$ is continuous. The bounds change in the integrals because it is what happens when one does a variable substitution in an integral. Finally, the notation $f\sim g$ means that $f$ is equal to $g$ multiplied by a quantity that tends to $1$ (when $x\to 0$ here)

Comment: I still don't understand the justification for saying the left integral is equal to the right integral multiplied by a quantity that tends to 1, is that justified by simply take a limit? also, when substituting the bounds a,b they should be replaced with g(a),g(b) where g is the substitution function (in out case I believe its $x^2 v$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Some sort of justification for the use of equivalents ($\sim$) is needed here. One way is to use $\epsilon, \delta $ to justify this.

Comment: @snatchysquid If a function $\varphi(x)$ has a limit $\ell \not = 0$ when $x\to 0$, then $\varphi(x)\sim \ell$. Here the integral on the left tends to the integral on the right because $h(x^4 u^2 v^2)$ tends to $1$ when $x\to 0$ uniformly with respect to $u, v \in [0,1]$. As Paramanand Singh's said, one can detail this step with a $\epsilon, \delta$ argument.

Comment: Alternately the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem also gives the convergence of this integral because $h$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$.